# R: How to obtain a list of variables by analysing a piece of code?

Tags: r, metaprogramming

Say I have piece of code that looks like

```r
afn <- function(code) {
    # return a list of variables used in code
}
```

I want `afn` to "analyze" `code` and return a list of variables and functions that it uses. E.g.

```r
afn({
  c = hn(gn(a) + fn(b))
})
```

should return

`list(
  vars = c("a", "b", "c"), 
  fns = c("fn","gn", "hn")
)`.

Is there a function in R that can do that?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `substitute` and `all.names` and `all.vars` which will get close to what is needed.

```r
afn = function(code) {
  sc = substitute(code) # this will substitute `code` for the code
  an = all.names(sc)
  av = all.vars(sc)
  list(vars = av, fn = setdiff(an,av))              
}
```

If `code` is actually a function then the below ugly hack will work (I am sure there is a much more elegant way)

```r
fn_definition = function(a, b){
  hn(fn(a) + fn(b))
}

library(magrittr)
afn2 = function(fn) {
  new_code = deparse(substitute(fn)) %>% 
    paste(collapse = "\n")

  fn_as_code = parse(text = glue::glue("bquote(.({new_code}))")) %>% 
    eval %>% 
    deparse %>% 
    paste(collapse="\n")

   parse(text=
      glue::glue("afn({fn_as_code})")
   ) %>% eval
}

res = afn2(fn_definition);res
#$vars
#[1] "a" "b"

#$fn
#[1] "function" "{"        "hn"       "+"       
#[5] "fn"
```

Comment: How do you pass an existing function to `afn()`? Is there some way to use something like `functionBody` e.g. `afn(functionBody(my_function))`?